# Mac OS X: In Objective-C or C, how to unload (stop) a LaunchDaemon managed by launched

Tags: objective-c, macos, launchd

I would like to know how to write Objective-C or C code to unload (stop) a LaunchDaemon.
The LaunchDaemon that I want to unload is running as root user.

My question is basically the same as this one: [How to Load LaunchDaemon plist from my Mac Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478614/how-to-load-launchdaemon-plist-from-my-mac-application).  The only difference is that he/she is trying to load, but I want to unload.

Comment: C code: `setuid(0); system("launchctl unload /Path/to/daemon.plist");`

Comment: Thanks, H2CO3.  But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure your program has root privileges?

Comment: It has admin privilege.  My program can delete a .plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons.  Before I delete it, I want to unload it first.

Comment: Did you try the AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges as in code from the link? The fact that application has privileges doesn't mean that it will exec launchctl as root. You should do it explicitly.

Comment: @cody `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` has been deprecated for a while, as discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated

Comment: @GrahamLee, I know, thanks. That wasn't a suggestion to use this function, that was a question.

Comment: @H2CO3 you can only `setuid(0)` in a process that already had UID 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use applescript

```
do shell script "launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.yourcompany.app.plist" with administrator privileges
```

Answer (score 2):

From C you can use the `SMJobRemove` function. If the job is in the system launchd context (i.e. it's in /Library/LaunchDaemons and is loaded—if not launched—at system startup) then you'll need to use Authorization Services to acquire the `kSMRightModifySystemDaemons` right, and pass the authorization reference to this function.

```
    AuthorizationItem authItem = { .name = kSMRightModifySystemDaemons,
        .valueLength = 0,
        .value = NULL,
        .flags = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults };
    AuthorizationRights authRights  = { .count = 1,
        .items = &authItem };

    AuthorizationRef authorization = NULL;
    OSStatus authResult = AuthorizationCreate(&authRights,
                                          kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment,
                                          kAuthorizationFlagDefaults | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed | kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize | kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights,
                                          &authorization);
    if (authResult != errAuthorizationSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't create AuthorizationRef: error %i", authResult);
    } else {
        CFErrorRef error = NULL;
        BOOL removeResult = SMJobRemove(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, jobLabel, authorization, waitOrNot, &error);
        AuthorizationFree(authorization, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults);
        // handle either success or failure
    }
```

The `waitOrNot` flag should be set to `YES` if you want to block until the job has been unloaded—this could potentially take a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've already used Parag Bafna's answer long ago, but forgot to mark it as the answer.